# Check for row in Python list based on first two elements

Tags: python

I have a moderately long Python list that looks like the following (showing first 5 rows):

```
In [4]: dfdist_list[:5]
Out[4]: 
[[10255, 10256, (-89.572, 41.235), (-89.025, 41.431000000000004), 37.963909],
 [10255, 937, (-89.572, 41.235), (-101.209, 36.184), 11622.426262],
 [10255, 3392, (-89.572, 41.235), (-101.221, 36.008), 11621.601622],
 [10255, 306, (-89.572, 41.235), (-101.53399999999999, 36.241), 11599.87664],
 [10255, 7313, (-89.572, 41.235), (-103.331, 35.109), 11475.272909]]
```

The first two columns of the list are ID numbers for start and end nodes (order not important).  The next two columns are the nodes' geographic coordinates.  And the last column is the calculated distance in miles between the nodes.

I'm looping through a CSV file to create this list.  But for each loop, before I perform the calculation, I want to check to see if there is already a row in the list with the same nodes but in reverse order.  (If so, then I'll skip adding the new row, because that data is already in there.)

What is the clearest/simplest way to check if a row exists in a list, where you know the first two elements of that row?

Update:  In particular, I tried the following which seems like it should work, but I can't get it to spit out a True/False.  It just spits out that generator object line:

```
In [18]: any([indexY,indexX] in subl[:2] for subl in dfdist_list)
Out[18]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000A902FC0>
```

Comment: You could sort the first two numbers and compare those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a parallel `set` while you are constructing the `list`. Something like this:

```
#UNTESTED 
existing_lines = set()
distances = []
for line in csv_file:
    t = tuple(sorted(line[0:2]))
    if t not in existing_lines:
        distances.append(line)
        existing_lines.add(t)
```

Comment: The important thing here is that you *sort* the id numbers, so that they are always in some order (ascending, descending, whatever). Once you have that, you might be able to change your outer algorithm to stop when the numbers go out of order (depending on how you generate the ids).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list, then you can check if another is in it like this:

```
test_list = [
    (10255, 10256),
    (10255, 937),
    (10255, 3392),
    (10255, 306),
]

print (10255, 10256)[::-1] in test_list

test_list += [(10256, 10255)]

print (10255, 10256)[::-1] in test_list
```

Output:

```
False
True
```